# Webdrivermanager is unable to download geckodriver 0.33.0 on Mac

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, robotframework, geckodriver, webdriver-manager

Im working in a robot framework automation project, and im trying to implement WebdriverManager to manage my webdrivers, but when i run `webdrivermanager firefox` it always download version 0.29.0 (outdated since 2021):

```
user@user-mbp Hydra-Manager % webdrivermanager firefox        
Downloading WebDriver for browser: "firefox"
Driver binary downloaded to: "/Users/cesar/Library/Application Support/WebDriverManager/gecko/**v0.29.0**/geckodriver-v0.29.0-macos/geckodriver"
Symlink created: /Users/cesar/Library/Application Support/WebDriverManager/bin/geckodriver
WARNING: Path "/Users/cesar/Library/Application Support/WebDriverManager/bin" is not in the PATH environment variable.
```

I also tried to specify the geckodriver version using the fallowing command `webdrivermanager firefox:v0.33.0`, also i tried all these version 0.33, 0.32, 0.31, or 0.30, and they always fail with the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Error, unable to determine correct filename for 64bit mac
```

I tried downloading the geckodriver from the official page and it works perfectly, but webdrivermanager not.

Does someone know what im doing wrong?